# Editing a Github repository by external users via API

Tags: php, api, github, octokit

We would like to create some kind of wiki and store all articles in a github repository.
As usual in a wiki, the articles should be able to be created or supplemented by anyone*.
Now it would be nice if this would not be possible via the Github page, but from our wiki itself.
For this Github has a fairly extensive API as an interface.

*Authentication via a Github account necessary.

After some research, I found two possibilities:

- via the browser [OctoKit](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.js)
- via the server [KnpLabs/php-github-api](https://github.com/KnpLabs/php-github-api/blob/master/doc/repo/contents.md#update-a-file)

I would prefer the browser side way, because it does not require a backend.
But the way via PHP seems to be easier for me.

Therefore, first my question, whether the following is possible via Octokit:

- Authentication of a user with his Github account
- Change / add files in my repo under his name

### edit

After the first comment, i decided not to go the "browser-way". But the way via PHP does not work either, because i just have a webspace with limited access rights (to /.ssh) so i have to lokk for a very different way...

Comment: If you want the user to be able to directly make changes to your repo, you probably need to invite them to it with the correct permissions. Just remember that they then would be able to push changes to your repo outside of your app as well and also bypass any validation you might have in your frontend code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to authenticate a GitHub user with their GitHub Account, you need to register a GitHub app or an OAuth app, which you can do in your user account settings or a GitHub organization settings.

For your case, I recommend a GitHub app. It must be installed on a repository in order to grant access, while OAuth Apps are for access tokens with global access.

I don't know PHP, but creating one with JavaScript is fairly straight forward, I just created a new one recently on Glitch:
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/twitter-together

When registering the GitHub App, you need to provide a redirect URL which needs to point to your website. The user will be redirected with a `?code=...` query parameter which you will need to exchange for an user access token.

See GitHub's documentation at https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps#web-application-flow